# regular expression: I want to select the second .* from the following create .*\[.*\]

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have  a big text file in notepad ++ i want to modify a replace a bunch of create table sql scripts, by appending _tmp to each table name

i want to turn   `CREATE TABLE [schema].[table] into [schema].[table_tmp]`

my find expression so far:    `create .*\[.*\]`

this finds the whole line, i want to find only the table name.

and then what do I put in the replace with box?

Comment: I don't use Notepad++, but does `(CREATE TABLE \[\w+\]\.\[\w+)` (replace with `$1_tmp`) work?

Comment: @melpomene Thanks for trying, that finds the whole line up to the final ]

Comment: And does the replacement work correctly?

Comment: @melpomene oh lol yeah that works, it does exactly what I need, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Search for: `(CREATE TABLE \[\w+\]\.\[\w+)`
Replace with: `$1_tmp`

We look for the text "CREATE TABLE [", followed by one or more word characters (i.e. the schema name), followed by "].[", followed by another word (the table name). We capture all of this with `(` `)`.

The replacement inserts the text we captured (`$1`) and adds `_tmp`.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `create table (\[.*?\]\.\[\w+)\]`
- Replace with: `$1_tmp]`
- *UNcheck Match case*
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
create table    : literally
(               : start group 1
  \[            : open bracket
  .*?           : 0 or more any character, not greedy
  \]            : close bracket
  \.            : a dot
)               : end group 1
\[              : open bracket
.*?             : 0 or more any character, not greedy
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1              : content of group 1 (ie. the first pair of bracket)
_tmp]          : the new table name
```

**Result for given example:**

```
[schema].[table_tmp]
```

Comment: IIUC the OP want to append "_tmp" to existing table names - eg `[foo].[bar]` to `[foo].[bar_tmp]`, so you'll have to extend your group to include the table name too